# Rediculous explorer.exe RAM usage: >18GB with >600'000 handles

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, windows-explorer, memory-leaks

For a while now I have the problem that explorer.exe sometimes starts using ridiculous amounts of memory. If I wait long enough it can sometimes increase up to 18GB (I have 8GB of RAM total but it uses mostly swap space). I'm using Windows 10 Home 1909 (build 18363.836).

I noticed using Process Hacker that explorer.exe opens literally hundreds of thousands of handles to the following registry key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{DFFACDC5-679F-4156-8947-C5C76BC0B67F}\Instance
```

(Peak today was over 628'000 handles total, almost all to this key, growing in the end with ~100 per second, adding up to almost 13GB until I decided to restart it.)

According to https://winaero.com/blog/clsid-guid-shell-list-windows-10/ this is the CLSID for the "delegate folder that appears in Users Files Folder", but I'm not sure what that means.

The contents are a single string with key `CLSID` and value `{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}`, which according to the same website is the "Shell File System Folder". (I don't really know how the CLSID system works.)

At first I presumed that it was probably some shell extension that I have installed, but I've already tried to disable most (if not all) of them and I still got a notification that explorer was using multiple GBs of RAM (in the meantime I wrote a simple program that checks for this). (I guess I'll continue trying and keep this updated if I do make a breakthrough.) Or could it be a problem that I gave icons to some folders?

Does anyone know what the cause might be? Or what I could do to further investigate the issue? If some specific useful info is missing, let me know!
I'm not sure if this question has a higher chance of being answered on [support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/), but I'll try to ask it there if I don't get an answer here.

Comment: Do you have any new [shell extensions](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)?

Comment: Also, if you go into the Explorer preferences, in View / Options, then in the Display / View tab (mine's in French, sorry), do you see an option to open folders in a different process? Is it checked? If so, uncheck it, and restart Explorer (not necessarily your PC, just the explorer.exe process in Task Manager). You can also log out then back in afterwards, but that's not mandatory. Your pagefile seems to be on the big side, if it peaks at 18+GB for 8GB of RAM. Setting it at a fixed 2048MB should be enough. That, or turn if off altogether, just to check on your Explorer RAM consumption.

Comment: Check for malware as well. What is happening is not normal on any machine working correctly.

Comment: @user1686 I've had the problem for quite some time now, so I'm not sure if the problem started after a certain extension...

Comment: @Didier It's not checked, but I did notice that (at least this time) there were two explorer.exe processes running. I set my page file size to automatic. Is there a benefit to reducing the size? Sounds like the RAM usage will just become a problem faster. 8GB is already sometimes a bit small when having many Firefox tabs + one or more IDE instances open.

Comment: There should be only one explorer.exe process running at any given time, unless it started to crash, automatically started a new instance, and for some reason, the first explorer.exe process wasn't terminated by the system. You should kill the one with the smaller PID when that happens, and see how it goes, RAM-wise. As for your pagefile, if set too low, yes, you might get a low-memory warning, but you could also set a RAM disk, and point your temp and tmp folders at it, so as to use your RAM as much as possible, and not write to disk, but then it's not ideal when coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this exact issue since Windows 8.1 and it just got worse in Windows 10 (explorer crashing every hour due to using too much memory). Disabled all shell extensions, disable all visual effects, even disabled thumbnails to no avail.

Your comment contained enough clues for me to finally track down the issue, so thank you!

The problem was that I added my home folder to "This PC" and it caused a slow but seemingly exponential growth of DFFACDC5-679F-4156-8947-C5C76BC0B67F handles. Only the home folder is causing the issue, other custom directories are fine. I'm now using Quick Access instead.

Comment: Oh wow! After performing a reinstall solved the issue I reinstalled shell extensions one-by-one, but the problem did not return. Later I used [Winaero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/winaero-tweaker/) to add my home folder to This PC (which I had done on my old install) and it seemed like the problem maybe returned, so I removed it again and told myself I would investigate it further to confirm later, but I never got around to that. Seems like this was the problem after all, nice find! And odd issue...
Interestingly, the CLSID does not seem to open the home folder, do you know what it refers to?

Comment: Ah wait, nevermind, I forgot the *first* CLSID description does include "Users Files Folder"

Comment: This has solved a year long issue for me. Up to this point, I had to restart Explorer at least once a day - after removing the user folder from Explorer's home via Winaero Tweaker, the problem disappeared! Thank you so much! <3